# C# using enum from Web Service as an array

Tags: c#, arrays, soap, enums, wsdl

I'm consuming a web service with C# and have recently updated to latest version from the WSDL.

There was a partial class in there called ValuationRequest with a

```
private SearchType valuationTypeField;
```

However this has been updated to

```
private SearchType[] valuationTypeField;
```

but I'm struggling to use it as an array.

I previously used it like so:

```
            request = new ValuationRequest
            {
                ValuationType = SearchType.lettings,
                Postcode = model.Postcode,
                FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
            };
```

However, this no longer works as SearchType.lettings is expected to be something like SearchType[].lettings, however no matter what I try, I can't get this working.

Any ideas at all how I can modify this to use the field as previous?

Any help at all is appreciated, and I can provide more information if required.

Cheers

Comment: How about `ValuationType = new SearchType[] { SearchType.lettings }`?

Comment: This throws no errors but for some reason still seems to be going through as a sales request. Can't quite see why